# Как все-таки запустить fsck?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Внутри `Hyper-V` стоит `Ubuntu 18.04.1` внутри которой с недавних пор появились ошибки на виртуальном диске. Размонтировать диск из `recovery mode` не получается из-за ошибки с занятостью устройства. Запланировать запуск с помощью `touch /forcefsck` и `FSCKFIX=yes` в `/etc/default/rcS` не получилось - команды игнорируются.

Comment: посмотрите какие процессы запущены. прибейте максимум из них, оставьте буквально init, и то что относится к вашей сессии, перемонтируйте корень в read only (`mount / -o remount,ro`) попробуйте fsck. Если и так проблемы, то при наличии доступа к меню загрузчика загрузите ядро с параметром init=/bin/bash в этом случае ваш bash будет единственным процессом в системе, а корень будет скорее всего уже в RO

Comment: Я не разбивал диск. корень - это весь /dev/sda2. Как в моем случае быть?

Comment: В общем то так же. уж init=/bin/bash гарантированно помогает. ни одного другого процесса в системе не будет, а bash писать на диск не нужно. из под него спокойно можно выполнять /sbin/fsck -f /dev/sda2  обратите внимание, никаких переменных окружения то же нет, поэтому все команды надо писать с полными путями

Comment: Получилось запустить fsck и он что-то исправил, но после перезагрузки в нормальном режиме и запуске fsck -n -f - опять показал ошибки. Как так?

Comment: А до перезагрузки, при повторном запуске он больше ничего не находит ? тогда это может потому что вы проверяете (-n -f) рабочую файловую систему и конечно на ней есть некоторые несоответствия когда она в работе

Comment: До перезагрузки ничего не находит. После перезагрузки, когда проверка возможна в режиме только чтения - находит ошибки. В результате появились ошибки чтения БД mysql и как следствие его частое падение.

Comment: когда файловая система уже смонтирована на запись fsck может находить ошибки и это нормальное поведение. Потому что ОС продлжает что то менять пока fsck читает и конечно он может увидеть что то частично записанное. А ошибки чтения БД вообще не могут появляться из за сбоев на уровне структуры файловой системы, которые видит fsck. При повреждении ФС могут пропадать файлы или становиться нулевой длины. Но не порождать ошибки чтения на существующих файлах, да еще периодически возникающие.

Comment: В логе mysql вот так https://pastebin.com/Eh5pmzcJ

Comment: Лучше системные логи смотреть. И в виртуалке и на хост машине. Ошибки ввода-вывода должны оставлять следы. Если бы это была не виртуалка, я бы решил что ошибка на жестком диске